# Marker click event not firing for ui-gmap-marker in Map Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an app with a controller for the Google Map. The click event does not fire when I run it on my phone. However, the click event fires when I test it on the ripple emulator.  Below is the map page and the corresponding Controller.

```
<ons-toolbar>
<div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
<div class="center page-title">Map MapController2</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" refresh="true" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">

    <ui-gmap-marker idkey="marker.id" ng-repeat="marker in map.markers" coords="marker" icon="marker.icon" click="onMarkerClicked()">
        <ui-gmap-window show="windowOptions" coords="marker" closeClick="closeClick">
            <div style="color: black">
        {{marker.title}}<br/>
        at {{marker}}
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>

</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

```
// Map Controller
app.controller('MapController2', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    var data = {};

    data.map = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {
            latitude: 27.949,
            longitude: -81.958
        },
        markers: [
            {
                id: 1,
                icon: 'img/blue_marker.png',
                latitude: 27.949,
                longitude: -81.999,
                title: 'This is where you are asdf;lkj  asdf;lj  ;asdf;lkasf; ;jasdfpoiarwtonmsad'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                latitude: 27.949,
                longitude: -81.958,
                title: 'Job Site'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                icon: 'img/plane.png',
                latitude: 27.949,
                longitude: -81.94,
                title: 'Airport'
            }]
    };

    $scope.windowOptions = false;

    $scope.onMarkerClicked = function () {
        this.windowOptions = !this.windowOptions;
    };

    $scope.closeClick = function () {
        this.windowOptions = false;
    };

    $scope.map = data.map;
});
```

Comment: is this a hybrid app with: `Ionic and Angular Material`? if so, then there's some issue with using any version of ionic + angular material v7.1 and up and `ng-click` not working. [https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1826](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1826)

Comment: Thank you. It is Ionic and AngularJS. I am new to Angular. I am using click instead of ng-click if that makes a difference. I built my app from a template that does not have the same problem which is odd.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was experiencing the same problem as you, but I was having the marker click basically log in the console, but then the changes weren't applying in the view.  I resolved it by concluding the click function triggered by the marker with a $scope.$apply().

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution after a lot on digging. The HTML I am using is below. I am using “ui-gmap-markers” (with an “s”) instead of “ui-gmap-marker”. Also, I had to encapsulate the Google map with ’data-tap-disabled=”true”’ to get it to work on the phone.

```
<ons-page class="map" ng-controller="MapController2" sliding-menu-ignore="true">

    <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
        <div class="center page-title">Map MapController</div>
    </ons-toolbar>

    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" refresh="true" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" data-tap-disabled="true">

        <ui-gmap-window show="map.window.show" coords="map.window.model" options="map.window.options" closeClick="map.window.closeClick()">
            <div style="color: black">
                {{map.window.title}}
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
        <ui-gmap-markers idkey="marker.id" models="map.markers" coords="'self'" doCluster="false" fit="'true'" icon="'icon'" events="map.markersEvents " options="'options'"></ui-gmap-markers>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>

</ons-page>
```

And then the Controller looks like this:

```
// Map Controller
    app.controller('MapController2', function($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
        var data = {};

        data.map = {
            zoom: 12,
            center: {
                latitude: 27.949,
                longitude: -81.958
            },
            markers: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    icon: 'img/blue_marker.png',
                    latitude: 27.949,
                    longitude: -81.999,
                    title: 'This is where you are'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    latitude: 27.949,
                    longitude: -81.958,
                    title: 'Job Site'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    icon: 'img/plane.png',
                    latitude: 27.949,
                    longitude: -81.94,
                    title: 'Airport'
                }],
            markersEvents: {
                click: function(marker, eventName, model, arguments) {
                    console.log('Marker was clicked (' + marker + ', ' + eventName);//+', '+mydump(model, 0)+', '+mydump(arguments)+')');
                    $scope.map.window.model = model;
                    $scope.map.window.model = model;
                    $scope.map.window.title = model.title;
                    $scope.map.window.show = true;
                }
            },
            window: {
                marker: {},
                show: false,
                closeClick: function() {
                    this.show = false;
                },
                options: {}, // define when map is ready
                title: ''
            }
        };

        //$scope.window = false;

        $scope.onMarkerClicked = function (m) {
            //this.windowOptions = !this.windowOptions;
            console.log('Marker was clicked');
            console.log(m);
        };

        $scope.closeClick = function () {
            this.window = false;
        };

        $scope.map = data.map;

    });
```

Comment: and you can specify an offset on the `ui-gmap-window` with `{pixelOffset: {width: 0, height: -40}}` in options attribute for example

Comment: Can we have plunkr for this?